# Change border color on legend in Chart.js

Tags: chart.js

I would like to remove or change the color of my border on the legend fields.

Today, there is a grey border but I can't change the color, I would like it to be like the color of the box.

I have tried to add a `borderWidth` in legend without success.
I managed to change the border color in the graph but I can't do it in the legend.

This my Chart code:

```
    var chart = document.getElementById("chart-out-rating");
    var myChart = new Chart(chart, {
      type: 'bar',
      data: {
        labels: datasetPrimeurPrice.year,
        datasets: [{
          label: 'Prix HT',
          data: datasetPrimeurPrice.outingPrice,
          backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(255, 166, 48, 0.3)',
            'rgba(255, 166, 48, 0.3)',
            'rgba(255, 166, 48, 0.3)',
            'rgba(255, 166, 48, 0.3)',
            'rgba(255, 166, 48, 0.3)',
            'rgba(255, 166, 48, 0.3)',
            'rgba(255, 166, 48, 0.3)',
            'rgba(255, 166, 48, 0.3)',
            'rgba(255, 166, 48, 0.3)'
          ],
          borderColor: [
            'rgba(255, 166, 48)',
            'rgba(255, 166, 48)',
            'rgba(255, 166, 48)',
            'rgba(255, 166, 48)',
            'rgba(255, 166, 48)',
            'rgba(255, 166, 48)',
            'rgba(255, 166, 48)',
            'rgba(255, 166, 48)',
            'rgba(255, 166, 48)'
          ],
          borderWidth: 1,
          yAxisID: 'y-axis-1'
        },
        {
          label: 'Note',
          type: 'line',
          data: datasetPrimeurPrice.rating,
          fill: false,
          usePointStyle: true,
          backgroundColor: '#71B37C',
          borderColor: '#71B37C',
          hoverBackgroundColor: '#71B37C',
          hoverBorderColor: '#71B37C',
          yAxisID: 'y-axis-2'
        }
        ]
      },
      options: {
        tooltips: {
          mode: 'label',
          callbacks: {
            label: function (tooltipItems, data) {
              if (tooltipItems.datasetIndex == 0) {
                return data.datasets[tooltipItems.datasetIndex].label + ': ' + tooltipItems.yLabel + ' €';
              } else {
                return data.datasets[tooltipItems.datasetIndex].label + ': ' + tooltipItems.yLabel;
              }
            }
          }
        },
        scales: {
          xAxes: [{
            display: true,
            gridLines: {
              display: false
            },
            labels: {
              show: true
            }
          }],
          yAxes: [{
            type: "linear",
            display: true,
            position: "left",
            id: "y-axis-1",
            gridLines: {
              display: false
            },
            labels: {
              show: true

            },
            ticks: {
              beginAtZero: true,
              callback: function (value, index, values) {
                return value + " €";
              }
            }
          }, {
            type: "linear",
            display: true,
            position: "right",
            id: "y-axis-2",
            gridLines: {
              display: false
            },
            labels: {
              show: true,
              usePointStyle: true
            },
            ticks: {
              min: 75
            }
          }]
        },
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: true,
        showLines: false,
        legend: {
          display: true,
          labels: {
            borderWidth: 0
          }
        }
      }
    });
```

You can see the result on my page :
[Graph with Chart.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDDsn.png)

Answer (score 0):

What might work is setting the color of the border to transparent, or an opacity to 0 (same result). What you have now is:

```
borderColor: ['rgba(255, 166, 48)', ...]
```

What my example would look like is:

```
borderColor: ['rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)', ...]
```

Hope this helps you out and works ;-)

Comment: Alternatively you could try removing all "borderColor:..." attribute lines.